# Vue JS Chat App UI

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, vue.js

Good day everyone!
I am developing a Chat App using Laravel + Laravel Echo + Pusher and Vue JS
all the functionality are fine but I have a problem with the UI.

If you have a new chat, your message will display on the right side and if someone sends a chat on the chatbox, his/her message will display to the left.

I already made the UI

```
<div class="chat-log-container" id="chatlog">
    <div class="chat-log-content">
        <div v-if="currentSender === meSender">
            <ul id="mesender" class="me-sender" v-for="message in chats">
                <li>
                    <div class="sender-name" >{{message.user.firstname}} {{message.user.lastname}} 10:12 AM, Today</div>
                    <div class="sender-message wordwrap">{{message.chat}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
            <ul class="other-sender" v-for="message in chats">
                <li>
                    <div class="sender-name" >{{message.user.firstname}} {{message.user.lastname}} 10:12 AM, Today</div>
                    <div class="sender-message wordwrap">{{message.chat}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

whenever I make a message, all messages will display on the right, if someone sends a chat, all messages will display on the left.

Does anyone know how to make my messages display on the right and the other sender messages will display on left?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Phil i am so sorry, i forgot to write my question. :)

Comment: Why don't you try adding the css property `float:right` for the `mesender` div. So that all your messages will be pushed to the right and add `float:left` for the other div to move them to the left.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. it's working now, CSS is all fine.. i just add an indicator for who sends the message.